# Magento module clean deinstall

Tags: magento

i have a problem with installing and deinstalling a module in magento. after resinstalling a module, the previous configuration in the backend is still there.
I deinstalled the module via connect, checked the folders of the server for files that didnt got deleted but i couldnt find anything. No matter how many times i clear cache, delete cache manually from server, after reinstalling the module the configuration i have made in the backend keeps reappearing (the module in question asks for some pathes which i filled in when i first installed it).

So can anyone tell me where these data is stored so i can delete it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend database contains some data in a few tables by default.

There are rows in `core_config_data` for each variable possibly defined for the module, you will have to search it for the keys related to module.

There could be tables created for the module which you will can easily find by the module prefix to tablename.

Also there is a table `core_resource`, which lists the modules recognized as installed by Magento, which means they are version number controlled.

Comment: Thank you very much! i already found the data in core_config_data but i didnt found the core_resource stuff. Im always a bit frightened when it comes to manipulating something in the database, so my question is, is it save to delete all this stuff or should i just delete the stored values?